# Python Package For Multi-Threaded Spider w/ Proxy Support?

Tags: python, proxy, multithreading, web-crawler, pool

Instead of just using urllib does anyone know of the most efficient package for fast, multithreaded downloading of URLs that can operate through http proxies? I know of a few such as Twisted, Scrapy, libcurl etc. but I don't know enough about them to make a decision or even if they can use proxies.. Anyone know of the best one for my purposes? Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

is's simple to implement this in python.

> The urlopen() function works
>   transparently with proxies which do
>   not require authentication. In a Unix
>   or Windows environment, set the
>   http_proxy, ftp_proxy or gopher_proxy
>   environment variables to a URL that
>   identifies the proxy server before
>   starting the Python interpreter

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from urllib import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from Queue import Queue, Empty
from threading import Thread

visited = set()
queue = Queue()

def get_parser(host, root, charset):

    def parse():
        try:
            while True:
                url = queue.get_nowait()
                try:
                    content = urlopen(url).read().decode(charset)
                except UnicodeDecodeError:
                    continue
                for link in BeautifulSoup(content).findAll('a'):
                    try:
                        href = link['href']
                    except KeyError:
                        continue
                    if not href.startswith('http://'):
                        href = 'http://%s%s' % (host, href)
                    if not href.startswith('http://%s%s' % (host, root)):
                        continue
                    if href not in visited:
                        visited.add(href)
                        queue.put(href)
                        print href
        except Empty:
            pass

    return parse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    host, root, charset = sys.argv[1:]
    parser = get_parser(host, root, charset)
    queue.put('http://%s%s' % (host, root))
    workers = []
    for i in range(5):
        worker = Thread(target=parser)
        worker.start()
        workers.append(worker)
    for worker in workers:
        worker.join()
```

Comment: Also `urlopen()` function has optional `proxies` parameter, which will be useful if you'd like to set proxy from code.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but could someone explain why this doesn't possibly degrade to single-threaded operation? Say there's one url in the queue to start with. The five threads will compete for the url. Say the operation to crawl the page and add more urls takes some time. The other four threads that didn't get the original url will throw `Empty` and will stop looping, so you end up with just one thread doing work. Is that not the case?

Answer (score 1):

usually proxies filter websites categorically based on how the website was created. It is difficult to transmit data through proxies based on categories. Eg youtube is classified as audio/video streams therefore youtube is blocked in some places espically schools.
If you want to bypass proxies and get the data off a website and put it in your own genuine website like a dot com website that can be registered it to you.
When you are making and registering the website categorise your website as anything you want.