# python web crawler with thread support

Tags: python, multithreading

these day im making some web crawler script, but one of problem is my internet is very slow.
so i was thought whether is it possible  webcrawler with multithreading by use mechanize or urllib or so.
if anyone have experience ,share info much appreciate.
i was look for in google ,but not found much useful info.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a good, simple example on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628766/python-package-for-multi-threaded-spider-w-proxy-support) Stack Overflow thread.

Comment: +1 That is a good piece of sample code. I think I'll use that myself!

Answer (score 3):

[Practical threaded programming with Python](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/au-threadingpython/) is worth reading.

Comment: it great resource! :) in addition ,are there any some small script ? function with save result from crawled web page thanks

Comment: @paul, I don't know, what I needed for save fetched pages is just for demo purpose, pickle or sqlite or directly dir/file is enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Making multiple requests to many websites at the same time will certainly improve your results, since you don't have to wait for a result to arrive before sending new requests.

However threading is just one of the ways to do that (and a poor one, I might add). Don't use threading for that. Just don't wait for the response before sending another request! No need for threading to do that.

A good idea is to use [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/). It is a *fast high-level screen scraping and web crawling framework, used to crawl websites and extract structured data from their pages*. It is written in python and can make many concurrent connections to fetch data at the same time (without using threads to do so). It is really fast. You can also study it to see how it is implemented.

Comment: Thanks ! how about compare with mechanize? i mean..compare with speed
Thanks in advance

Comment: @paul: It will certainly be faster than mechanize. It is easier to do the right thing on it.