# Pathos, Dask, futures, which one to use for parallel cluster application?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, dask, pathos

I am confused here. I have an application that is CPU bounded so I went to implementing a parallelisation using multiprocess to overcome GIL issues.

I first tried to use `multiprocessing` and `futures` but I faced a pickling issue so I went to `pathos` which uses `dill` as a `pickle` replacement.

Everything is working but I am wondering if I am using the most "future proof" solution. I have seen also `dask`, but I don't know if it will work in case of pickling classes issues (see [Python: (Pathos) Multiprocessing vs. class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29121979/6522112)). From the doc, it uses `futures` so I am assuming that it won't do the job.

Secondly, I would like to be able to use two servers at a time and I have seen that this is possible with `pathos` (also `dask`), but I don't understand how exactly this works. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26948258/6522112 only shows how to use one server. How about using 2 or more? I can't find any example about that although it seems possible as described by the package info.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here is a great introduction how to set up a distributed cluster, that can be used as dask scheduler on different computing enivonments: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQro_CaP9Fo. However, the API has changed over time, so i recommend to have a look at https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html. How to use the distributed scheduler in dask is described here: http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/scheduler-overview.html

Comment: I went exact along the same path (from multiprocessing to dask), so maybe my experience might be of use. So far, I try to use dask as much as possible, since it provides more than plain multiprocessing. If this functionality is relevant for your application, give it a try. However, I sometimes ran into strange performance issues, that I was not able to track down, despite the very responsive community around dask. I am a beginner in python and you might be much faster than me in debugging those problem. In the rare were dask does not work as expected, I am currently falling back on pathos.

Comment: You may also want to do some reading on `gevent,` `tornado,` and `AsyncIO.` See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40166757/speeding-up-urlib-urlretrieve/40187270#40187270.

Comment: @ArcoBast: so you're saying that `dask` would be the way to go. I'll see the doc.

Comment: So did you get a conclusion yet?  I also heard someone tried protobuf for pickling so maybe that's another solution?